# Is there a way to draw attention to a new answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I added an answer to this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32733/anglican-minor-orders) which has been around for a while. It would be surprising if there was not a way to improve this answer if other community members read it and make suggestions.

Is there a way to gently encourage people to look at this answer to make it better or does a mechanism already exist for doing this of which I am not aware?

Comment: Related: [How can we encourage high-quality new answers to old questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4640/21576)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system already does this, though there are a few things you can do in addition.

First and foremost, every edit to a post, new answer to a question or several other actions will bump a post to the top of the home page. This means that everyone who visits that page will see your new post (and can navigate directly to the change by clicking the time stamp).

Additional things you can do is come to chat and talk about your new answer, add a bounty to the question to put it in featured questions (though really this is sort of silly for you to do as an answerer since you can't give the bounty to yourself). Finally you can promote the question and it's answers in other forums.

So pretty much, the system automatically should be putting some community eyes on every new post.

Answer (score 3):

So I was fiddling around on here and found the "active" page which I had not noticed before and that this question was top of the list. Looks like the answer to this question is there is already a way of doing this and that it happens automatically.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.